# "Possible loss of fraction" only sometimes marked

Tags: c#, int, double, resharper

Why does ReSharper mark the following result-assingments as "Possible loss of fraction"

```
double result;

result =  10 / 2;
result = -10 / 2;

result = (10 / 2);
```

where it does not mark it in the following expression

```
result = -(10 / 2);
```

The `-(10/2)` actually happened in my code (with 10 being a variable), which sometimes caused off-by-one errors due to Integer-Math.
This was clearly an oversight at programming time, but the fact that ReSharper can in general detect it makes me wonder why it doesn't always when assigning to a double afterwards.

I can understand why ReSharper doesn't mark it for int-assignments. There are situations when I want integer-math ("find middle of the array", ...), but not when assigning to doubles.

Comment: report it to resharper team. there is nothing special happening here. I would say its false positive warning.

Comment: Here is Resharper issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP. First search if there is similar bug reported, and if not - report it.